# Invalid value for initial Heap size

Tags: neo4j

I try to increase the `HEAP` for `Neo4j` running in a Container. The Container has `30GB` Memory.
However specifying

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=2g
```

results in an error:

```
Starting Neo4j.
Invalid initial heap size: -Xms2g
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I'm using `Neo4j 4.1.1`. `java -version` gives

```
openjdk version "11.0.9" 2020-10-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.9+11)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.9+11, mixed mode)
```